# int to std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

The ultimate goal of this is converting a 32-bit integer to an STL vector container of bool.

Is it possible avoiding iterating through the number's bits?

One way would be getting access to the raw pointer:

```
void int2bin(int number){
    // Initialize the vector
    std::vector<bool> container(32);
    // Get low level buffer access
    void* addr = &container[0];
    // Copy number bits to the structure
    memcpy(addr, &number, sizeof(int));
}
```

But because vector is special case of STL I can not get access at the raw address but to the proxy reference object.

Is there a way to bypass this?

Apparently `std::bitset` does that, but I have not find a way to cast it to a `std::vector<bool>` without iterating.

Comment: Why would you want to use `vector<bool>`? One of C++'s biggest  mistakes.

Comment: There’s no way without iterating. As Neil said, you probably don’t want to use `std::vector<bool>`. Either stick with `std::bitset` or a more appropriate container (from a third party library).

Comment: To get to the raw memory of the vector, you need to call the member function data().

Comment: @DigitalEye: There's the small problem of `vector<bool>` not being a regular vector.

Comment: @DigitalEye `data()` returns void with `std::vector<bool>` so this can not be done this way

Comment: @MSalters: I should've been more clear in my response. I was not advocating using data() on a vector<bool>. Microsoft's implementation of vector<bool> doesn't even provide the data() method. I was merely stating that calling data() is the best way to get a pointer to the vector's elements.

Comment: I have seen some "bit processing" using "bool" type of data for example in 4G LTE encoding but typically those have been represented as uint8_t or similar. Maybe it can "save" 8-fold of memory but I doubt it was worth doing. This vector<bool> seems interesting sidetrack I must say :D.